# AG Grid Cannot Refresh Data

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am placing my grid within an Angular 2 component. Within the grid component constructor I call two functions which return the columnDefinition and the rowData and these returned values are placed in variables. I then set the gridOptions using the variables:

```
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = this.columnDefinitions;
    this.gridOptions.rowData = this.rowData;
```

I have a button above my grid which calls a function to calculate new rowData and corresponding columnDefinition. I set my variables with the new rowData and columnDefinition and then update the grid as follows:

```
// Set the column definition.
this.columnDefinitions =  this.gridService.getAllGroupColumnDefinitionsByHour(this.startDate, this.finishDate);

// Set the row data.
this.rowData = this.taskDataService.getTaskGridDataByHour(this.startDate, this.finishDate);

this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.rowData);
this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefinitions);
this.gridOptions.api.refreshView();
```

My grid, however, retains some of the original columns and adds the new columns. My first image shows the grid when the application loads:

[image: Initial grid]

Here is the grid after replacing the rowData and the columnDefinition:

[image: Replaced rowData and columnDefinition.]

Here is the complete GridComponent class code:

```
export class GridComponent {

private gridOptions: GridOptions;
private columnDefinitions = [];
private defaultColumnDefinitions = {};
private rowData = [];
private startDate: Date = new Date(2017, 3, 1);
private finishDate: Date = new Date(2017, 3, 12);

constructor( private taskDataService: TaskDataService, private gridService: GridService ) {

    // Initialise the grid.
    this.initialiseGrid();
}

initialiseGrid() {

    this.gridOptions = {};

    // Set default options.
    this.gridOptions.headerHeight = 24;
    this.gridOptions.showToolPanel = false;

    // Get the initial default column definitions.
    this.defaultColumnDefinitions = this.gridService.getDefaultColumnDefinition();

    // Get the initial column definitions.
    this.columnDefinitions = this.gridService.getAllGroupColumnDefinitionsByDay(this.startDate, this.finishDate);

    // Get the initial row data.
    this.rowData = this.taskDataService.getTaskGridDataByDay(this.startDate, this.finishDate);

    // Set the gridOptions properties.
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = this.columnDefinitions;
    this.gridOptions.defaultColDef = this.defaultColumnDefinitions;
    this.gridOptions.rowData = this.rowData;
}

zoomHour() {
    //alert("zoom hour");

    // Set the column definition.
    this.columnDefinitions = this.gridService.getAllGroupColumnDefinitionsByHour(this.startDate, this.finishDate);

    // Set the row data.
    this.rowData = this.taskDataService.getTaskGridDataByHour(this.startDate, this.finishDate);

    // Set the column width.
    this.gridOptions.defaultColDef.width = 32;

    this.updateGrid();
}

zoomDay() {
    //alert("zoom day");

    // Set the column definition.
    this.columnDefinitions = this.gridService.getAllGroupColumnDefinitionsByDay(this.startDate, this.finishDate);

    // Set the row data.
    this.rowData = this.taskDataService.getTaskGridDataByDay(this.startDate, this.finishDate);

    // Set the column width.
    this.gridOptions.defaultColDef.width = 32;

    this.updateGrid();

}

updateGrid() {

    // Set the gridOptions properties.
    this.gridOptions.api.setRowData([]);
    this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([]);
    this.gridOptions.api.refreshView();

    this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.rowData);
    this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefinitions);
    this.gridOptions.api.refreshView();

}
}
```

Can anyone offer any guidance to prevent this please?

Comment: need more code for configuration of the AGgrid

Comment: Hi. I have edited my post to include the grid's class. Thanks for your interest. Let me know if you need any further code. I am going to continue debugging today.

Comment: My mistake (hands up). I had two functions in my data service class which calculated the column definitions and returned the results. In error I was using the same variable to hold the column definition. I've learnt a little more about Typescript scope and the differences between `let`, `const` and `var` along the way.